# How to programmatically determine current setting for Option Base in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I programmatically determine the current setting for `Option Base` in VBA? The `Option Base` can be set to `0` or `1`, and this determines whether array indices start at `0` or `1` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)).

However, I can't see any easy way to find out what the current setting is. I was hoping there might be an `Option()` function that I could pass a parameter to, something like:

```
Debug.Print Option("Base")
```

and it would tell me, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this? If you use `LBound` and `UBound` it doesn't matter which setting is used.

Comment: You may define an array and look if `LBound` is `0` or `1`. But if the` option base`  is determined by coder, why same person need to find it. Search the `Option Base` statement in the code to find it.

Comment: Downvoter/Close voter. It would be nice if you left a comment explaining what you find so unclear. Looks pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I agree with @jonsharpe that if you're using `Lbound(arr)` and `Ubound(arr)`, you don't need to know this at runtime, but I think it's an interesting question.

First, an example of properly looping through an array.

```
For i = LBound(arr) To Ubound(arr)
    ' do something
Next
```

---

Now, in order to do *exactly* what you asked, you'll need to access use the `VBIDE` library. Otherwise known as the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility" library. It provides access to the IDE and the code with-in it. You can use it to discover if `Option Base 1` has been declared. I don't recommend trying to do it at runtime though. This would be more useful as a kind of static code analysis during development.

First, you'll need to [add a reference to the library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515446/3198973) and [grant the code access to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23738721/3198973). Once you've done that, the following code should do what you would like.

```
Public Sub FindOptionBase1Declarations()
    
    Dim startLine As Long
    startLine = 1
    
    Dim startCol As Long
    startCol = 1
    
    Dim endLine As Long
    endLine = 1 ' 1 represents the last line of the module
    
    Dim endCol As Long
    endCol = 1 ' like endLine, 1 designates the last Col
    
    Dim module As CodeModule
    Dim component As VBComponent
    For Each component In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents ' substitute with any VBProject you like
        Set module = component.CodeModule
        
        If module.Find("Option Base 1", startLine, startCol, endLine, endCol, WholeWord:=True, MatchCase:=True, PatternSearch:=False) Then
            
            Debug.Print "Option Base 1 turned on in module " & component.Name
            
            ' variables are passed by ref, so they tell us the exact location of the statement
            Debug.Print "StartLine: " & startLine
            Debug.Print "EndLine: " & endLine
            Debug.Print "StartCol: " & startCol
            Debug.Print "EndCol: " & endCol
            
            ' this also means we have to reset them before we look in the next module
            startLine = 1
            startCol = 1
            endLine = 1
            endCol = 1
        End If
        
    Next 
    
End Sub
```

See the [CodeModule.Find documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443952(v=vs.60).aspx) for more information.

---

If using an add-in is an option, @Mat'sMug and I's open source project [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com/) has a [Code Inspection](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/wiki/Code-Inspections) that will show you all instances of this throughout the active project.

[image: Option Base 1 Code Inspection]

[See this for more information on that particular inspection](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/wiki/OptionBaseInspection).

Comment: Isn't it easier to just create an array and check its `LBound`?

Comment: Awesome answer and I expect one could easily modify this to work with other `Option`s and maybe even create the hallowed Option() function for which I seek. @jonsharpe is right it was a somewhat academic question but I am glad you found it interesting too. It's a beast of a routine though and scrolling to the top of the module (yes I know about Ctrl+Home) doesn't seem like such a bad idea after all. ;)

Comment: Yeah. Sure it is @jonrsharpe, but that's not what OP asked.

Comment: @RubberDuck strictly, they asked for *"any easy way to find out what the current setting is"*! But this is a thorough answer nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. The VBIDE is an area of interest for me.

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks. Looks like you actually have a practical application for this.

Comment: No @Caltor. It wasn't. I didn't realize the feature was implemented, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
Function GetBaseOption() As Long

    Dim arr

    arr = Array("a")
    GetBaseOption = LBound(arr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution. I wonder if you could one line this successfully in the immediate window.

Comment: @RubberDuck sure just change it to a function and return the `LBound` instead of printing it and you can use it in the Immediate no problem.

Comment: @RubberDuck -  I don't know what context that would run in (if you ran it completely in the Immediate window) - might be unreliable since you can have different Base settings in each code module.

Comment: Maybe... It's worth noting that Option Base is at the module level, so this function will return the value for the module it's defined in, not where it's called from.

Comment: Lol. Yes. I'm lagging. My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 1):

### Simply use:

```
LBound(Array())
```

...to return the current **[`Option Base`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement)** setting.

---

### Or, as a function:

```
Function optionBase() As Byte
  optionBase = LBound(Array())
End Function
```