# Macro to open VBA editor

Tags: excel

Is there a code that would open the VBA editor and find and replace text?

Even if it does not do find and replace, is there a code that would just open the VBA Editor?

Comment: Do you mean having a macro open an editor and making edits to another macro during runtime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509578/change-vba-coding-with-vba-coding

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: @Torc Yes.. so having a code that would open macro and then make changes within the script of another macro. so from one report to another if that makes sense.

Comment: @Saima, have a look at the links that BigBen posted. They'll show you how to do that