# Change String in VBA code over MANY workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping that @TimWilliams sees this. About 2 years ago he replied to a question regarding changing a string in multiple spreadsheets with the below VBA. I am trying to do the same, but not change a string in worksheets, I am trying to change a string in the VBA modules of the different spreadsheets (to change the directory path as we are moving from a mapped drive to the cloud). I was wondering if the below can be adjusted to do that?

Thanks

```
Sub ReplaceStringInExcelFiles()

    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim orig As String
    Dim news As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    orig = "cow"
    news = "dog"

    FilePath = "C:\myDir\"
    MyFile = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls*")


    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile) '<< assign the workbook to wb
        'Loop over the worksheets
        'Note: no need to activate/select
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.UsedRange.Cells.Replace what:=orig, _
                            Replacement:=news, _
                            lookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False
        Next ws
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Haven't tried anything as no idea

Comment: Not an answer to your question: but you should change from hard coded path to e.g. a name (maybe hidden so that users aren't able to change it). Then it will be much easier to change it next time.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515446/7446760 - it should give you enough to get going.

Comment: Welcome Mark! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour