# How to solve the Excel VBA Run-time error '13', type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

The macro code initially works perfectly fine until I try to add a button to trigger the macro, it kept showing run-time error '13', type mismatch. Below is my macro code which works perfectly fine until I used the code to add button to trigger the macro. The code for macro and button is in different module.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Summary")
    Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("E2")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Examples")
    Set Rng2 = WS2.Range("F2")
    
    ' Clear original data on Summary
    i = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng1.Offset(i, 0))
        Rng1.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = 0
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng2.Offset(0, i))
       If Rng2.Value <> "" Then
            Rng1.Offset(0, 0).Formula = "='" & WS2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([7], [1]).Address 'Project
            Rng1.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "='" & WS2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([9], [1]).Address 'Model
            Rng1.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "='" & WS2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([10], [1]).Address 'ID`
            Set Rng2 = Rng2.Offset(0, i + 1)
        End If
            Set Rng1 = Rng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check
    Loop
   i = 0
    ' Clean up
    Set Rng1 = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set Rng2 = Nothing
    Set WS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is the code for creating the button and assigning it to the macro

```
Sub CommandButton_Click()
    Dim b As Button
    Dim ws10 As Worksheet
    Set ws10 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Summary")
    Set b = ws10.Buttons.Add(200, 5, 80, 18.75)       ' left, top, width, height
    b.OnAction = "test" ' a sub name in module
    b.Characters.Text = "Refresh"  ' text on the button
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code? At which line execution fails? Do you create a new button at each click???

Comment: Hi, I tried debugging the code already the error occurs right after the IF statement, which is the line at the end that is highlighted, and I can't progress anymore. And no, the button is a one-time thing. But I even tried manually adding button and assigning the macro the same error occurred.


`Rng1.Offset(0, 0).Formula = "='" & WS2.Name & "'!" & Rng2.Cells([7], [1]).Address 'Project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your current `Sub CommandButton_Click()`

- `ws10.Buttons.Add(200, 5, 80, 18.75)` - why do you create a new button each time you click on it?
- `b.OnAction =`  - this is C# code, not VBA

This simple code should be enough:

```
Sub CommandButton_Click()
    Call test
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help do you know how I can create a button in VBA and then assign it to call test?

Comment: you can create it manually once and it'll be there forever. Why do you want to create it through VBA?

Comment: To assign action to a button programmatically, you need to have your running code and button in separate workbooks. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509578/change-vba-coding-with-vba-coding)